# Assigning a reference with if statements?

Tags: c++, reference

In C++, we can assign a reference using the conditional operator as such:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    int &k = (false) ? i : j;
}
```

Is it possible to do this with if-else statements? I don't see how you can do it because you can't reassign a reference.

Comment: `int& k = [&]() -> int& { if (false) return i; else return j; }();`

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper` is a rebindable reference equivalent: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: "*I don't see how you can do it because **you can't reassign a reference**.*" - you answered your own question.  That being said, maybe consider using `std::reference_wrapper`, which *can* be reassigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, but you probably don't want to.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    bool cond = false;
    int &k = [&]() -> int& { if (cond) return i; else return j; }();
}
```

Or, if you're allergic to stupid lambda tricks:

```cpp
int& pickARef(bool cond, int& trueRef, int& falseRef)
{
    if (cond)
    {
        return trueRef;
    }
    else
    {
        return falseRef;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    bool cond = false;
    int &k = pickARef(cond, i, j);
}
```

Neither one looks like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) when you need a re-assignable reference, eg:

```cpp
#include <functional>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    std::reference_wrapper<int> k;
    if (condition)
        k = i;
    else
        k = j;
    // use k/k.get() as needed
}
```

Though, in this case, I would just use a pointer instead:

```cpp
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    int *k;
    if (condition)
        k = &i;
    else
        k = &j;
    // use *k as needed
}
```